# RestTemplate junit5 - “ResponseEntity.getBody() because is null”

Tags: java, mockito, resttemplate

I have a working method:

```
public Country getCountry() {
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.set(SYSTEM_CODE, "code");
   ResponseEntity<Country> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
            properties.getUrl(),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity(headers),
            Country.class);
    return responseEntity.getBody();
   }
```

and testing:

```
Country country = new Country();
country.setId(1);

ResponseEntity<CountryPage> mockEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(country, HttpStatus.OK);

Mockito.when(mockEntity.getBody()).thenReturn(country);

Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
            ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Country>>any()))
            .thenReturn(mockEntity);

//do
some.getCountry();
```

result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()" because "responseEntity" is null
```

why it is defined as `null`.
I found similar situations but I did not help me.

Comment: which line causes throwing an NPE? I am concerned about the ```Mockito.when(mockEntity.getBody()).thenReturn(country);``` as it looks like the ```mockEntity ``` has not been mocked by you actually. Therefore, there is no way to stub behaviour of non-mocked instance. Can you check if removing this line resolves your problem?

Comment: @marcin.programuje - return responseEntity.getBody(); When delete line Mockito.when(mockEntity.getBody()).thenReturn(country); not resolve problem

Comment: Are you getting the same error or is it something different?

Comment: @marcin.programuje  - the same error

Comment: you need to set `clientRestTemplate` in your class, check if any other object is present in `restTemplate` field

Comment: @RDK sorry, fix post clientRestTemplate -> restTemplate

Comment: `mockEntity` isn't a mock but a regular class, so trying to register behavior on that with mockito will obviously not work. Just remove that line and use the plan `ResponseEntity` which you created.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didnt understand what you mean, what return in .thenReturn (?);

Comment: `Mockito.when(mockEntity.getBody()).thenReturn(country);` this line doesn't make anysense as `mockEntity` isn't a Mockito mock but just a regular instantiated instance of `HttpResponse`. So trying to register behavior on that will not work as it isn't a Mockito mock.

Comment: When delete line Mockito.when(mockEntity.getBody()).thenReturn(country); - not resolve problem

Comment: plz show us the code where you are initialising `some` object, it is important.